# Opening a virtual serial port created by SOCAT with Qt

Tags: qt, serial-port, socat

I'm developping a Qt5 application on MacOS.

I would like to test my application serial port communication.

I'd like to use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) but I'm unable to open the port created with socat: *QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()* lists only the */dev/cu-XXXXXX* ports...

Comment: What about opening the port directly without getting available ports?

Comment: How? QSerialPort can only be initialized by a file name (only port name or QSerialPortInfo&).

Answer (score 3):

Socat port creation example:

```
socat  pty,link=/dev/mytty,raw  tcp:192.168.254.254:2001&
```

After this you get your pseudo port `/dev/mytty`

Now you can reference this port via [QSerialPort](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtserialport/qserialport.html#QSerialPort-2)

```
serial = new QSerialPort("/dev/mytty");
```

Comment: When trying to open the serial port, I have a "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: Can you tell me more about your socat command? where are written the data sent through the /dev/mytty serial port?

Comment: `socat` makes a connection to `192.168.254.254:2001` and then every byte, that comes from `/dev/mytty` will be automatically sent to `192.168.254.254:2001` and every byte from `192.168.254.254:2001` will be sent to `/dev/mytty`. You can take `netcat` to test this `socat` connection.

Comment: Thank for the info! It is very strange because I have always this "no such file or directory" when opening with *QSerialPort* but it works fine with *QFile*... I think I will end up to do my test with *QFile*.

Comment: This will not work with QtSerialPort. For some reason, it can't open pts

Comment: I didn't mention I'm on OSX

Answer (score 1):

You might be having troubles because of the symlink.

You could try something like this:

```
QFileInfo file_info("/dev/mytty");
QSerialPort* serial = nullptr;
if (file_info.isSymLink()) {
  serial = new QSerialPort(file_info.symLinkTarget());
} else {
  serial = new QSerialPort(file_info.path());
}
serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

You could also construct a QSerialPortInfo class with those paths instead of creating a port directly.

Comment: I always have this "No such file or directory" error. I tried to construct my own QSerialPortInfo class by overriding the *systemLocation()* method, but it isn't virtual.

Comment: Could this perhaps be a permissions issue then?

Comment: no I tried to create in another path without permission issue without success

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a permission issue.
Make sure the user running your application has permition to access the virtual port.