# Test and log serial port commands with qt in a virtual serial port

Tags: c++, linux, qt, serial-port

I have a program written in c++/QT communicating with external devices via the serial port. Now I want to log what the program is writing, and what receiving, but without interfering with the program. Thus I wanted to create a virtual serial port connecting the logging program and the original program, while the logging program is connected to the real serial port. That would enable two things: Logging of the commands without interfering, and enabling a test mode, where the logging program just writes values back without being connected to a real serial port.
My problem is: When using `socat`, I run in the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867628/opening-a-virtual-serial-port-created-by-socat-with-qt). When using `tty0tty`, I get a compilation error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599209/compiling-tty0tty-results-in-error).
Thus, what can I do in order to place a logging program in between the original program and the serial port? The original program uses `QSerialPortInfo` in order to get the available serial ports, rendering `socat` useless.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/112957). You can use `slsnif`, and if you need to know how it's implemented, you'll have to look in its innards. There's not much Qt specific to it.